# Running into SSL errors with gcloud app deploy

Tags: python, python-3.x, ssl, gcloud

The `gcloud app deploy` used to run fine until I started getting SSL errors.

`MaxRetrialsException: last_result=(None, (<class 'ssl.SSLEOFError'>, SSLEOFError(8, u'EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:727)'), <traceback object at 0x109ce8518>)), last_retrial=3, time_passed_ms=326169,time_to_wait=0`

I am on a MAC OS CATALINA using python 3.7.

Comment: This error could mean that the connection closed during the SSL handshake. Hence, I believe that there could be an underlying local network issue, such as a firewall or a proxy configuration. Can you please check your network connection and retry?

Comment: I could not find any firewall or network issue. I did check my network connection. Could not find any issue

Comment: Hi, I just deployed and run a [Hello World application](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/quickstart#deploy_and_run_hello_world_on_app_engine) on App Engine without any issues, so I was not able to reproduce the issue. Can you check whether you encounter the same issue by running other `gcloud app` commands such as `cloud app describe`? Because if you **can** run other commands sucessfully, this means that the issue may be on your side.

Comment: I would like to mention that you can append `--log-http` flag to your `gcloud app deploy`, such as `gcloud app deploy --log-http` to gather more information in the logs about the issue and look into it deeper. Also, if you are behind a proxy or firewall from a corporate, you may not be able to access the internet with the default settings. Check the following [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/proxy-settings).

Comment: `gcloud app describe` works. This is what I get with `gcloud app deploy --log-http` 
==== request start ====
uri: https://storage.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/runtime-builders/o/experiments.yaml?alt=media
method: GET
== headers start ==
Authorization: --- Token Redacted ---
Range: bytes=0-104857599
accept: application/json
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate
content-length: 0
range: bytes=0-104857599

Comment: One thing is. The `deploy` works when I'm using a VPN. Is there problem with requests from south Asia. Specifically Bangladesh?

Comment: I believe that this issue may be related to your ISP in Bangladesh. I would highly recommend that you reach out to them regarding this, as it stands right now, it looks like the ISP is filtering out those requests. From their reply, you will understand if the blocking of these requests were intentional or not. Keep me posted!

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. It seems it is a problem with the ISP. I will contact them to clear this matter. I'll keep you posted.